# GSON Deserialization to an ArrayList<T> not working

Tags: java, json, deserialization, gson, json-deserialization

I have an ArrayList of  objects(tweet is a class that I have defined in my package). Now, I have written this ArraList as a JSON object into a file using GSON. Moving on, I am now  reading this JSON object into an ArrayList using GSON. However, when I iterate through this newly read ArrayList, I am not able to cast it back into a tweet object. Even though the ArrayList is actually a collection of tweet objects in itself. The exception I am getting is :
***com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to tweet***

contents_array_tweets is an arraylist of tweet objects.

contents_array has also been declared as an arraylist of tweet objects.

Here is the code:

```
f.write_file("Content_Array_JSON_full.json", gson.toJson(ob.contents_array_tweets), false);

ob.read_file("Content_Array_JSON_full.json",f);
ob.contents_array = gson.fromJson(ob.file_contents, ArrayList.class);
for(i=0; i<ob.contents_array.size(); i++){
        stn_1 = ob.contents_array.get(i).stemmed_nouns;
        ob.contents_array.get(i).sim_tw = new HashMap<Integer, Double>();
//This is where I get the exception. I am not able to access stemmed_nouns and sim_tw which are class variables of tweet.
    }
```

Comment: Please, remove all the code, which is **not needed** for understanding the problem; show the little non-working part of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ob.contents_array = gson.fromJson(ob.file_contents, ArrayList.class);
```

Instead of a raw `ArrayList.class` you should use a [`TypeToken`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html) to tell Gson the actual runtime type of the ArrayList's type parameter:

```
ob.contents_array = gson.fromJson(ob.file_contents,
    new TypeToken<ArrayList<tweet>>(){}.getType());
```